# Regex C# Finding a string from two words in any order

Tags: c#, regex

Given : two words; "new", "intermediate"

I need to find any string that contains the two given words,

Good Strings:

- "This is the new and intermediate way of doing this".
- "This is the intermediate and new way of doing this".

Bad Strings:

- "This is new and limited".
- "This is intermediate or limited".

The rules are:

- both "new" and "intermediate" must be in the strings.
- case should be ignored
- the order of the words does not matter
- the position of the match is not important.

TIA

This seems to work, but is there a better way?
^(.*?\bnew\b.*?\intermediate\b.*?)|(.*?\bintermediate\b.*?\bnew\b.*?)$

Edit: My question maybe the same, except I'm in C# not Ruby (does it make a 
difference?)

Edit: Checking the suggested answer, shows it works for C# Regex. Sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: Does it need to be a reflex? Why not `.Contains()`?

Comment: @Enfyve Nope...but I am trying to learn Regex better. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha, was unsure.

Comment: @Enfyve  Is C# Regex different from Ruby?

Comment: For the most part, no. Afaik they both use the pearl implementation of regex. In any case, the concepts of lookaheads (which is why I think you're aiming for) is the same.